# Why in this code we listen to resize event on fixed position iframe instead of actual div

Tags: javascript, resize

I've never seen this approach before -> so I'm curious if it's in fact provides any speed benefits.

Code found here: `https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/dist/Chart.js` 
So seems like author injects an iframe that is absolutely positioned size and sized the same as parent and listens to resize event on iframe instead of actual element. Question - why?

```
helpers.addResizeListener = function(node, callback) {
    // Hide an iframe before the node
    var hiddenIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var hiddenIframeClass = 'chartjs-hidden-iframe';

    if (hiddenIframe.classlist) {
        // can use classlist
        hiddenIframe.classlist.add(hiddenIframeClass);
    } else {
        hiddenIframe.setAttribute('class', hiddenIframeClass);
    }

    // Set the style
    hiddenIframe.style.width = '100%';
    hiddenIframe.style.display = 'block';
    hiddenIframe.style.border = 0;
    hiddenIframe.style.height = 0;
    hiddenIframe.style.margin = 0;
    hiddenIframe.style.position = 'absolute';
    hiddenIframe.style.left = 0;
    hiddenIframe.style.right = 0;
    hiddenIframe.style.top = 0;
    hiddenIframe.style.bottom = 0;

    // Insert the iframe so that contentWindow is available
    node.insertBefore(hiddenIframe, node.firstChild);

    (hiddenIframe.contentWindow || hiddenIframe).onresize = function() {
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Er... The frame is positioned absolute, so the frame has to be resized. What do you expect? :)

Comment: If I were making a function to insert something into a page and wanted to handle resize events, then I'd also assign them to the thing I'd just created.  For all you know the size & positioning style may change later and a resize of the parent may not be an appropriate trigger.  In my mind, this is so clearly the better approach.